# Why doesn't Code::Blocks build my .exe file?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have just installed a fresh Code::Blocks instance, however the build button doesn't work: I have pressed it many time to build the .exe file, but when I try to run it asks me to build it again.

The "Yes" button on the pop-up dialog that asks me to build doesn't do anything.

My complier's installation directory is C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW

I'm using Code::Blocks 20.03 with MinGW installation pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a version of GCC as compiler (such as MingW for Windows), chances are it will come with support for the most recent version of C++ disabled by default. This can be explicitly enabled by going to *Settings*->*Compiler*

[Example](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/codeblocks/codeblocks1.png)

And here, within *Global compiler settings*, in *Compiler settings* tab, check the box *Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard*

[Example](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/codeblocks/codeblocks2.png)

Comment: I have checked those options but it doesn't help in my case. I suppose it is the GNU/GCC's issues

Comment: @PhátT Have you tried by going to ```Build``` > ```Run```?

Comment: The example links here are broken.  Inline the examples in the answer, rather than external links.